# Swap control+click with shift+click

Tags: shortcut

Ctrl+click is like Window's shift+click in the explorer - selects everything from point to point. Shift selects additively. What are the names of their controls in the preferences menu? I want to swap them (so that ctrl+click adds to selection).

Comment: What are you talking about, what context? 3D View, File Manager, Outliner? For each editor there are different Key bindings for different operators. Anyway, change on the top dropdown menu to search for the keybinding (instead of operator name) then switch the keys or change the operator settings to suit your need.

Comment: I am talking 3D view Edit mode. I tried searching for the "Shift" key and "Ctrl" key but there are just too many results.

Comment: See under *3D View > Global > Activate/Select* operator is `view3d.select`

Comment: Nope, tried them - they don't work. Uppon swapping, shift + click stops working completely while ctrl + click works the wery same way as before the change.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>  used to select shortest path.

Try to change it to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>, then change *Select* in *Mesh* to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>.

I didn`t change every other options in selection, but it is ok for me